# how to deploy keycloak container in production openshift?

Tags: openshift, keycloak

i found an official guide how to deploy keycloak container in openshift in development mode, but is there any guide how to deploy keycloak container in production mode in openshift with external db?

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you use the Keycloak Operator to deploy your keycloak.

Keycloak Custom Resource has an option to use external database as follows:

```
apiVersion: k8s.keycloak.org/v2alpha1
kind: Keycloak
metadata:
  name: example-kc
spec:
  ...
  serverConfiguration:
    - name: db
      value: postgres # plain text value
    - name: db-url-host
      value: postgres-db # plain text value
    - name: db-username
      secret: # Secret reference
        name: keycloak-db-secret # name of the Secret
        key: username # name of the Key in the Secret
    - name: db-password
      secret: # secret reference
        name: keycloak-db-secret # name of the Secret
        key: password # name of the Key in the Secret
```

*: https://www.keycloak.org/operator/advanced-configuration

Comment: no, i dont use keycloak operator, i deployed usual keycloak pod. Is it better to use keycloak operator?

Comment: Depending on the Maturity level of Operator, the operator helps to manage resources deployed by the operator. 
As far as I checked, KeyCloak Operator can do seamless upgrade, backup and so on..
So, I would say using Operator is better than not using it.
https://operatorhub.io/operator/keycloak-operator

Comment: ok, thx. I deployed keycloak in production mode without operator.